# Responsive child div scale to fit parent width, overflow height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to find the best way to get a responsive scrolling `div` that either scales or zooms to fit the container. I've got a fiddle of where I'm at here:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t53zouj1/8/)**

What I'd like to have is the `#scale` element to be displaying a width of 400px and height at 320px, so scaled or zoomed to 80% of the original. The `#wrap` element needs to retain the ability to scroll down and see all of `#scale` also.

I need this because in my application the `#contain` div changes size all the time. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do overflow auto like that it is the browser who put the scrolling bar if it is necessary  i hope that is what you looking for

and if you want the width to be 80% of #wrap you just give him the width 80% like that it always stays 80%

```css
#contain{
  width:400px;  
  border: 1px green dotted;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
  padding:10px;
}

#wrap{
  height:250px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px red solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

#scale{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px blue dashed;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="scale">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the `#contain` div has dynamic width in my situation. It needs to scale with that. In this situation it just happens to be 80%.

Comment: So like this it is 100% and it will always scale with it!